# jQuery ui.selectmenu not being populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have been working on a dashboard using jquery ui and have come across the ui.selectmenu.js for converting boring html select menus into jquery ui look 'n' feel select menu, but I am having some issues where is appears to not be loading my select list contents.

I have tested the implementation, using pre-populated options for the select list, and these are displayed in the ui.selectmenu correct. However, it appears that when I attempt to populate the option list on the fly, there is an issue with the list box - it's empty!

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery(function($){
            $.getJSON('src/versions.php', function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, val){
                        $('<option/>').attr('value', val.version)
                        .html(val.version)
                        .appendTo('select#release_id');
                    });
                });
            });

        $('select#release_id').selectmenu({
            style:'dropdown',
            width: 250,
            maxHeight: 500
        });
```

The above code returns a json list of values and appends them correctly to the options list. This can be observed from firebug when looking at the html code. When I compare this code to a pre-popuated list, again the ui.selectmenu, there appears to be a slight difference - the ui.selectmenu is updating a  element of the value select; this does not happen when using code above.

Overall, I believe that this is a timing issue, I'm just not sure how to verify, or prevent code from loading in the incorrect order.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Add / Delete / Modify Options

According to these docs: [Github jQuery UI Select Menu](https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/wiki/Selectmenu), one modifies the options within one's ui selectmenu by adding / removing / modifying the options in the original select, then calling `$('#select').selectmenu();` again.

> It's possible to rename an option or
>   even add one to the selectmenu. Simply
>   change the original select element and
>   apply `selectmenu()` to it:
>   `$('select').selectmenu();`

### Example

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var select_menu = 'select#release_id';

    var init_select = function(selector) {
        $(select_menu).selectmenu({
            style:'dropdown',
            width: 250 ,
            maxHeight: 500
        });
    };

    jQuery(function($){
        $.getJSON('src/versions.php', function(data) {

            // Don't want to init_select more than once per AJAX request
            var count = data.length;
            $.each(data, function(key, val){
                $('<option/>').attr('value', val.version)
                    .html(val.version)
                    .appendTo(select_menu);
                });

                // Second initialization, using extra options AJAX'd in
                if (--count == 0) init_select(select_menu);
            });
        });

        // First initialization, using whatever options present at page-load
        init_select(select_menu);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the info Michael, I will try and see how this works.